# Unable to run maven command from command prompt but executes sucessfully through eclipse

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have added all dependencies(my project ,junit,etc) and surefire plugin. so it is executing successfully in eclipse but when run through command prompt it throws error. below is the attached screenshot. and the pom.xml file . embeeded maven settings in eclipse works.maven location is also getting recognised from command prompt
[BUILD FAILURE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVFlo.png)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>



  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>



   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

   <!-- Dependency for POI API -->
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>


    <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore> false </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>

                </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: could you share the `<build>` information of your pom.xml please and what command are you running from command prompt?

Comment: You may have different maven versions installed. Please make sure your eclipse and terminal maven is the same

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049166/maven-compilation-error-when-run-through-command-line-cucumber-maven-project/46049751#46049751

Comment: <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore> false </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
          
                </plugin>                       
        </plugins>
    </build>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, it says maven try to download a depedency jar from this remote maven center repository:  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Because this repository is a SSL website, you need to install its certification to pass the auth. And Maven run by JDK, so you need to import the certication into JDK Security Store.

The reason why you can pass in eclipse is eclipse use a different settings.xml as run maven command, maybe eclipse not use the SSL repository.

There are two options: 
1) Don't use SSL maven remote repository, specify a HTTP repository:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 in your manve settings.xml, like below:

```
<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>securecentral</id>
      <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
         Maven Super POM -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

2) Import certification in JDK Security Store 
    find the step to import in this post:
    [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Comment: Thanks a lot.it worked. i was stuck in this since 1 month

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using two different maven,usually eclipse comes with its own maven version. You can verify you are using same Maven installation in eclipse and from command prompt.

You can verify maven installation in eclipse by going to 
Preference--> Maven--> Installation.

From command prompt, check for Maven home/M2 home.

[image: Maven installation verify in eclipse]

Comment: so what exactly i should do. mine is selected as emebeded. it is clicked

Comment: in command prompt it is showing location of downloaded maven path

Comment: Add external maven using 'Add' button. select maven which you can see in command prompt. And solve the error. If you can share Pom file, it can help identify the problem

Comment: how to use embeeded maven in command prompt. if i use external maven from eclipse. it fails

Comment: It might be in m2e plugins, but i would suggest, it is advisable to use that. Always use maven installed as independent program and solve POM issues

Comment: i have writen some part of pom.xml in comment section

Comment: From error, it seems like proxy issue with Maven, you need to configure JAVA_HOME and proxy in settings.xml file under conf folder of maven. But it would be helpful if you share full POM and full error stack

Comment: added pom.xml yogi.please check

Comment: @heardm-- i just google about error, it seems like some SSL error. You can follow below links for more details: 
 [SunCertPathBuilderException] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp)