# Maven 3.5 build error

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have installed maven latest version 3.5 ,iam trying to build a fuse project and getting below error and warning.

output of mvn -version in command prompt:

```
C:\Temp\Fuse6.3>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T20:39:06+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Temp\fuse 6.3\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Temp\fuse 6.3\java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Can you please help.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.company.esb.fuse:core:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to redhat-ga-repository (https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga): Cannot access https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnect
orFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.company.esb.fuse:core:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to jboss-earlyaccess-repositor (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/): Cannot access http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/ with type default using the available connector
factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.260 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-23T10:58:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.esb.fuse:core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.company.esb.fuse:core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630262: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630262: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.camel:camel-core:pom:2.17.0.redhat-630262 from/to redhat-ga-repository (https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga): Cannot access https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga with type default using the availab
le connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: No transporter factories registered -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: looks like proxy error, check out [proxy doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention.The same is working from Jboss developer studio and dependencies are downloaded successfully.i have used the same setting.xml in Eclipse maven user settings configuration.The issue is happening only in command prompt.

Comment: OK, in that case check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049166/maven-compilation-error-when-run-through-command-line-cucumber-maven-project/46049751#46049751)

Comment: I have attached the output of mvn -version and i have set all the required environment variables.

Comment: I think it's your proxy, do a mvn help:effective-settings to check your settings.